# Questions about Feature Placing Languages/Predicate Functor Logic

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

About a year and nine months ago, I poses a question here about Quine's predicate functor logic and ontological nihilism. I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around these ideas. I hope someone here can help me with the following questions:

The first question I have is where I can find a text that teaches predicate functor logic. Everything that I've looked at touches upon first order logic. Articles on ontological nihilism talk about PFL as a language for ontological nihilism but don't get into the mechanics.

MY second question has to do with the nature of "features" in a feature placing language. In my previous question, @Double Knot wrote, "Feature and relation boundary is not clear-cut and both are described as property via function/map in math and predicate in logic (number 2 can be also thought of as a doubling function)." Is this taken to mean that there is not a clear boundary between the idea of features and relations and/or that a feature is similar to the concept of a map in category theory?

Last, is it possible to recover the concept of a number from a feature placing language?

Thank you.

Comment: Steven Kuhn, [An Axiomatization of Predicate Functor Logic, NDJFL (1983)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-24/issue-2/An-axiomatization-of-predicate-functor-logic/10.1305/ndjfl/1093870313.full) and John Bacon, [The completeness of a predicate-functor logic, JSL (1985)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273980)

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA! Is there really no difference between features and operations/relations?

Comment: You are welcome :-)